# Android Studio 3.5.1 : Can't able to copy text from warning tooltip

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.5, android-studio-3.5.1

I have updated stable version of Android Studio 3.5.1 today. I am trying to copy string as below screenshot:

[image]

Its not copying anything and just closing it by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

How do I copy this? All the older version it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On Windows: Try,

1. Hover over the yellow popup text (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to see more text of that tooltip)
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **`LeftMouseClick`**
3. The **'Yellow Text'** will be in your clipboard, ready to paste.

#### On Mac, a slightly different dance than Windows.

- hold <kbd>shift</kbd>
- click **and hold** towards the end of the text(probably missing last character)
- keep holding mouse click and release <kbd>shift</kbd>
- while holding mouse click, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy
- paste wherever

That is it!

Sadly, Now we cant copy text which is selected in tooltip. If anyone find solution for same. Please share.